# When my function is called from onEdit it does not perform the same as calling directly

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

Per code below, a direct call to getWeather in the editor executes successfully to completion. But when triggered via onEdit in the spreadsheet, it properly displays my debug line "In getWeatherDaily1" but never completes after that. What am I doing wrong? I need to use onEdit to run my function.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Waypoints");

function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.source.getSheetName()==sh.getName()) {
    getWeather();
  };
};

function getWeather() {
  var lat = 34.639702;
  var lng = -84.191499;
  getWeatherDaily(lat,lng);
};

function getWeatherDaily(theLat,theLng) {
  var gpsURL = "https://api.weather.gov/points/" + theLat + "," + theLng;
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("In getWeatherDaily1 " + gpsURL + "."); // Debug
  var gpsResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(gpsURL, {method: 'GET',headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json','Accept': 'application/json'} });
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("In getWeatherDaily2 " + gpsResponse); // Debug
};
```

Comment: Log more of the steps to see what is going on. Not alerts `Logger.log(varToLog)`

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Not sure how to do that in the editor with onEdit. Can you give me a clue? I can run getWeather directly in the editor, but that is not where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check [My Executions](https://script.google.com/home/executions) for failed executions, and view those logs to learn more about why the function fails.

Chances are that the function is failing because it cannot access the `UrlFetch` class. [Simple triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) such as `onEdit(e)` run in a restricted context where not all classes are available. See [Authorization modes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/editor-auth-lifecycle#authorization_modes).

To make it work, use an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) instead of a simple trigger.

Comment: I didn't even know I could look at past executions. That's great. I see it is a permissions issue. The reason I'm using onEdit is to run this in my phone. Maybe installable triggers won't work on mobiles. I'll look into it.

Comment: Installable triggers work fine on mobile — Apps Script runs on Google's servers rather than in your end device.